# Angular Expression in Template not evaluating

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a page using ng-repeat, pulling in a template.
The template creates a checkbox and I am trying to set the "checked" value on it using the ternary operator.
I am adding it like follows...

```
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' {{val.isTrue ? 'checked' : ''}}>
```

But when I run this the expression is not interpreted. I just see the expression printed in the DOM.
I know the expression can evaluate because if I do...

```
<input type='checkbox' name='{{val.isTrue ? 'checked' : ''}}'>
```

or

```
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox'>{{val.isTrue ? 'checked' : ''}}
```

I can see the value printed.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ngChecked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked).

```
ng-checked="val.isTrue"
```